# searching inside array values to get primary key in php

Tags: php, arrays

I have the following format of an array:

```
$array = [
'fruits' => ['apple','orange','banana'],
'vegetables' => ['spinach','broccoli','lettuce']
];
```

I want to be able to search within the values of fruits and vegetables and get it to return the key (either fruits or vegetables).

I have used this:

```
$result = array_search('orange', $array);
```

but $result returns nothing. when it suppose to return 'fruits'. How do I go about doing that?

Answer (score 1):

can use foreach

```
$array = [
'fruits' => ['apple','orange','banana'],
'vegetables' => ['spinach','broccoli','lettuce']
];

foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    if (in_array('orange', $value)) {
        echo $key;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

array_search returns the index of the searched value if existed. so in my opinion you could do a foreach search and if array_search wasn't empty get the key.
something like this:

```
foreach ($array as $key => $value){
$result = array_search('orange', $array[$key]);
if($result!==false){
    echo "found in ".$key. "at index ".$result;
}
}
```

Comment: oh yeah, you're right. i've edited the answer. what do you think?

Comment: Yes, it looks fine now.